# Chrome driver for emulator and phone in Android

Tags: java, appium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying for automation in mobile phones for that i am using **appium**. I need latest chrome driver version that will work for **genymotion** emulator and real devices **both**, currently for my scripts to run in Emulator **chrome driver** ver 2.20 is working and for real devices chrome driver version 2.27 is working. Help me out with this issue.

Comment: Anybody please help me on above query.